# Linq C# Fetch rows from datatable where string length in column is greater than 49

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to linq.So need ur help.
I have created a data table from excel.
I need to fetch rows which has where string length in any of the  column is greater than  49.
I have written below query.

```
from x in excelDataTbl.AsEnumerable()
                            where x.Field<string>("OEM_NAME").Length > 49 ||
                            x.Field<string>("LEVEL1").Length > 49 ||
                            x.Field<string>("LEVEL2").Length > 49 ||
                            x.Field<string>("LEVEL3").Length > 49 ||
                            x.Field<string>("LEVEL4").Length > 49 ||
                            x.Field<string>("LEVEL5").Length > 49
                            select x
```

This is not working for me

Comment: Not working as in error or unexpected results?  Please post any errors or what your actual behaviour returns in your question.

Comment: Not returning any rows

Comment: And _do_ you have any fields greater than 49 characters in length in your sample data set?  Brackets would also be sensible.

Comment: I have column field which has 66 character.Brackets would also be sensible means??

Comment: Wrap each of your terms in brackets, such as `(x.Field<string>("OEM_NAME").Length > 49)`.

Comment: those would be `parentheses`, and are unnecessary if not doing complex logic.

Comment: I suggest you try to just retrieve those DataRows with a simple call to see if you can access them and view their properties in a debugger.

Comment: @user3794092 What you have shown us is a query definition that seems correct. You don't show what you do with it though... What do you do after this? Run a `foreach` or? Also, have you made sure that the `excelDataTbl` actually contains data?

Comment: I did a count on returned rows.But it is giving me Object reference to null error

Comment: @ps2goat And your arrogance was thoroughly unnecessary, thank you.

Comment: If i am not using ||(OR) operator and simply using column which has  value length > 49. i am getting rows.but when using OR operator its returning null

Comment: @user3794092 The null reference might be caused by a null value in one of the fields. If, for instance, the value in the `OEM_NAME` column on a row is `DbNull.Value` then the `.Length` would cause a null reference. Null does not have a length property...

Comment: @user3794092  yes this is the problem.Thanks dat's why it was giving null refernce

Comment: @user3794092 Good that you found the problem. For the future though, please remember to add as much context as possible when asking a new question. If you had added **"I get a null reference error when trying to do a `Count`..."** instead of **"This is not working for me"** in the original question, you would have gotten an answer faster and with much fewer comments...

Comment: @JaneS, I wasn't trying to be condescending.  It's just that `brackets` was confusing because it wasn't the normal term.  E.g., (curly) braces = `{ }`, (square) brackets = `[ ]`, parentheses = `( )`

Comment: @ps2goat Now I understand the context of your statement.  I'm fully aware of the differences between braces, brackets and parentheses but in my country the term "brackets" is used interchangeably with "parentheses" in a programming context.  We're just weird like that :)